# get descriptor of function object

Tags: javascript

I'd like to learn about `writable` value of a function object `FUNC`.

```
function FUNC(){}
```

When accessing properties, usually `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,prop)` is used. But in my case, I am not accessing properties, but the function object it self. I'd like to see if I can assign new properties to function object (I am aware of a hackish way, but I am interested if there is something else available).

How can I achieve this?

js:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(FUNC,"what do i put here?");
```

Comment: You can add properties to the function object with regular notation: `FUNC.prop = "value"` but that's not usually very useful. It might help to understand what you are really trying to achieve.

Comment: Property descriptors are associated with, well, properties, not values (a function is value). The function in and of itself doesn't have a descriptor. So the answer to your question as is is "not possible". But you may want to clarify your problem, because *"I'd like to see if I can assign new properties to function object"* is certainly doable and has nothing to do with property descriptors.

Comment: @FelixKling -- I read this a little differently to mean the OP was asking how to view something like `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(FUNC, 'prototype')`, which is possible. Rereading, this is confusing: " I am not accessing properties, but the function object it self"

Comment: @MarkMeyer: Possibly. The *"I am not accessing properties, but the function object it self"* is confusing me. edit: jinx

Comment: I am indeed trying to find out if I can assign a property / method to the function object. (even functions are objects in javascript).  I am working in an evironment that uses 3rd edition of ecmascript 262. I was assigning a method to the built in function object and after doing a `for(var i in FUNC )`, my method was not printed. Still don't know how they disabled `writability` of the FUNC

Comment: @potato What environment are you working in exactly? Maybe it's just buggy. Can you access the method after assigning it, is it only not printed or was it really not assigned?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to learn about `writable` value of a function object

An object doesn't have a `writable` value. Only individual properties are *writable* or not, `writable` is a *property attribute* (part of the *property descriptor*).

> I'd like to see if I can assign new properties to function object

You can add new properties on an object when it is *extensible*. You can check using [`Object.isExtensible`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/isExtensible).

Comment: Is there a similar method for ECMA-262 3rd edition? I am working in an environment that still uses that version

Comment: @potato No, there's not, but objects in ES3 couldn't be frozen or prevent extensions. Of course ES3 doesn't offer a proper way to deal with property attributes either, all it had was `Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that the question is: "how can I get the function object using `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,prop)` and assign new properties to it?"
There are a couple ways to do this, since [functions are objects in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function).

You can get the function object itself by using it's name - **but not calling it**. i.e the object of `function func() { // code }` would be accessed through the `func` variable (the variable the function was assigned when it was declared). As @Mark Meyer commented, you can then assign properties with `func.yourProperty = whateverValue`.

If you must use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj,prop)` to get the object, then you can use `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(func, "prototype")`. It will return something like this:

```
{
    configurable: false
    enumerable: false
    value: Object { … }
    writable: true
    <prototype>: Object { … }
}
```

where your function will be under the `value` and `value.constructor` property.

Another method of assigning properties (other than the one stated by @Mark Meyer), is `Object.assign`. You can use it like so to assign new properties to the function:

```
func = Object.assign(func, { yourProperty: yourValue })
```

**NOTE**: you must reassign the function variable for the new properties to remain after you call `Object.assign()`.